# What happened to EYRX?

Tags: operating-system

In 2001, Eyring Corporation released a 32-bit reconfigurable RTOS called EYRX. I remember downloading the documentation and programmer guide from their Web site. Strangely, no traces of that OS can be found anywhere on the Internet (except for the [brief mention on a defunct site](http://mil-embedded.com/products/id/?1419)). The system is not even on the [list of real-time operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_real-time_operating_systems), as if it never existed. Does anyone know what happened to EYRX?

Comment: There have been (and are) RTOSes ten a penny. There are a number of major ones that people still remember, and possibly thousands long forgotten. I must admit I've never heard of EYRX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What, [this documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20020408094251/http://www.eyrx.com:80/online.html)?

I found this by searching for Eyring on the Internet Archive, finding Eyring.com, going to their earliest 2002 snapshot and clicking on the EYRX link.

Unfortunately, the operating system itself was hosted on an FTP server, and those aren't archived by the Internet Archive. So we'll see if somebody else can find it.

Comment: In fact, yes, that one. It didn't occur to me to use the Internet Archive.

Comment: "this material is best viewed using a screen resolution of 1024x768 or higher" - awwwww.